Inverse Fourier Transform - convolution of exponential and rectangular window
I'm trying to get the response in the time domain of the convolution between the exponential $u(t)e^{-at}$ and the rectangular window ($u(t+1)-u(t-1)$). I had already obtained its result by integration, but I need to obtain its result by the convolution method, using the Fourier transforms.
So I got that the convolution between the two functions is a Fourier pair of the multiplications of these functions in the frequency domain. For the rectangular function, it is:
$\frac{e^{iw} - e^{-iw}}{iw}$ . For the exponential, it is: $\frac{1}{a+iw}$. Now I need to obtain the inverse Fourier transform of the multiplication of these two functions and I'm really stuck on this problem. Do I need to integrate or can I obtain it from Fourier pairs more easily? How can I integrate it?
$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{w=-\infty}^{\infty} (\frac{e^{iw} - e^{-iw}}{iw}).(\frac{1}{a+iw})e^{iwt} dw $

Perhaps the evaluation is simpler if you split it as follows $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{w=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i w}-e^{-i w}}{i w}, \frac{1}{a+iw},e^{iwt}, dw\=\frac{1}{2\pi} \left(\int\limits_{w=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i w}}{i w}, \frac{1}{a+iw},e^{iwt}, dw-\int\limits_{w=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-i w}}{i w}, \frac{1}{a+iw},e^{iwt}, dw\right)$$ and use the frequency shifting property to evaluate each of the two parts.

Thank you @StevenClark, I really needed help to figure that out.

Let $$f(t)=\mathcal{F}_w^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{i w\cdot \left(a+i w\right)}\right](t)=\mathcal{F}_w^{-1}\left[-\frac{i}{a w}-\frac{1}{a(a+i w)}\right](t)=\frac{2 u(t)-1}{2 a}-\frac{u(t) {\mathrm e}^{-a t}}{a}$$
Hence with shift in time domain
$$\mathcal{F}_w^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{i w}-e^{-i w}}{i w\cdot \left(a+i w\right)}\right](t)=f(t+1)-f(t-1)=\frac{2 u(t+1)-1}{2 a}-\frac{{\mathrm e}^{-a \left(t+1\right)} u(t+1)}{a}-\frac{2 u(t-1)-1}{2 a}+\frac{{\mathrm e}^{-a \left(t-1\right)} u(t-1)}{a}$$
Hint: $u(t)$ is the unit step function (Heaviside function).
Visualize with $a=1$:


Thank you @gpmath . I'm a beginner and I don't understand the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{-i}{aw}$. I had understood that the Fourier pair of $\frac{-i}{w}$ ( or $\frac{1}{iw}$) was $u(t)$, isn't that right? How could you obtain $\frac{2u(t)-1}{2a}$?

$$\mathcal{F}_tu(t)=\pi  \delta (w)-\frac{i}{w}\ne -\frac{i}{w}$$
